# How to handle "data" argument in a function?

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R with the standard `data` argument, i.e., the argument passes the name of a data frame, as it is done in `lm` function. I would like to have a function that may be called with:

```
func(a,data=d)
```

and without:

```
func(d$a)
```

`data` argument. For the sake of simplicity, let the function calculate the mean of a vector. How can I do it?

Comment: The data itself is usually passed to the data argument -- not its name.  e.g.. `mtcars`, not `"mtcars"`.  I think you are going to have to show some code to get answers.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at Hadley's Advanced R chapter on [Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html): it does a good job of walking through several examples that include this.

Comment: The "Advanced R" book is very informative. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possibilities.  The tests all use the builtin data frame `BOD`.

**1) S3** You can write an S3 generic with data.frame and default methods:

```
func1 <- function(x, data) UseMethod("func", if (missing(data)) x else data)
func1.data.frame <- function(x, data) mean(data[[x]])
func1.default <- mean

# test

func1("Time", BOD)
## [1] 3.666667

func1(BOD$Time)
## [1] 3.666667
```

**2) if** The above is a bit unusual and you may prefer just to use an if:

```
func2 <- function(x, data) if (missing(data)) mean(x) else mean(data[[x]])

func2("Time", BOD)
## [1] 3.666667

func2(BOD$Time)
## [1] 3.666667
```

**3) non-standard evaluation** You could also use non-standard evaluation although this is typically not recommended:

```
func3 <- function(x, data) {
   if (missing(data)) 
        mean(x)
   else
        eval(substitute(mean(x)), data)
 }

 func3(Time, BOD)
 ## [1] 3.666667

 func3(BOD$Time)
 ## [1] 3.666667
```

**4) formula**  Another way to approach it is to use a formula which must be of the form `~ X` where `X` is a column in `data` or an object in the formula's environment.  If `data` is omitted then it defaults to the caller's environment.  That is, it first looks in `data` and if *not* found there it looks in the formula's environment.

```
func4 <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("func4")
func4.formula <- function(x, data = parent.frame()) {
       p <- parse(text = all.vars(x))
       e <- eval(p, data, environment(x))
       mean(e)
}
func4.default <- mean

func4(~Time, BOD)
## [1] 3.666667

v <- BOD$Time
func4(~v)
## [1] 3.666667

func4(BOD$Time)
## [1] 3.666667
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I would not like `data` to be the first argument. In fact, the first argument for my function may be of `glm` class or be a numeric vector. (So `UseMethod` will do the switching for that first argument.)

Comment: You can specify the object to dispatch on to `UseMethod`.  See `?UseMethod`.  I have modified the example to make `data` the second arg; however, the construction is a bit unusual.

Comment: Please note that the definition of `func2` is invalid. Just try
`d=data.frame(a=1:10); func2(a,d)`

Comment: Your call should be `func2("a", d)` .

Comment: Have added more options.

Comment: Thank you! `func3` is just what I want.