# Writing Long Functions With a "data" Argument

Tags: r

I'm aware of how to write short functions using a `data` argument ([How to handle "data" argument in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463539/how-to-handle-data-argument-in-a-function)) - you can just copy and paste the body of the function and use an if-else statement to run the function depending on whether or not an argument is provided for the "data" argument. I have a much longer function, and I don't want to copy and paste the entire thing and use an `if` statement and change the code throughout the entire function.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(4:8), z = c(5:1))
my_fxn <- function(x, y, z, data) {
  aaa <- x ^ 2 + 5
  bbb <- (y * log(y) + 5) ^ 7
  ccc <- z + aaa
  ddd <- mean(c(x, y, z))
  eee <- aaa + bbb + ccc + ddd
  paste(eee, "my_fxn", eee, sep = "_")
}
my_fxn(df$x, df$y, df$z)
> my_fxn(df$x, df$y, df$z)
[1] "14500329.5724518_my_fxn_14500329.5724518" "64360436.579237_my_fxn_64360436.579237"   "240475836.750078_my_fxn_240475836.750078"
[4] "776392986.326892_my_fxn_776392986.326892" "2219080769.50416_my_fxn_2219080769.50416"
```

How can I concisely write a line (or a few lines) of code at the beginning of `my_fxn` to allow me to use the following line of code to generate the same answer from `my_fxn`?

```
my_fxn(x, y, z, data = df)
```

Update: I think my real problem is that the names of the data frame and the columns in the data frame do not match the names of the function's arguments. Why doesn't the following code work?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(6:10), z = LETTERS[1:5])
my_fxn <- function (aaa, bbb, ccc, data) {
  if (!missing(data)) {
    aaa = as.numeric(data$aaa)
    bbb = as.numeric(data$bbb)
    ccc = as.character(data$ccc)
  }
  print(aaa[1])
}
my_fxn(x, y, z, df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to copy and paste the entire function? Wouldn't you just use the same methods as in the SO thread you linked. ie just have a section of the code at the top specifying that `x, y and z` are equal to data

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(4:8), z = c(5:1))
my_fxn <- function(x, y, z, data) {

  if(missing(data)){
    x = x; y = y; z = z # unnecessary but just to be explicit
  } else {
    x = data$x
    y = data$y
    z = data$z
  }

  aaa <- x ^ 2 + 5
  bbb <- (y * log(y) + 5) ^ 7
  ccc <- z + aaa
  ddd <- mean(c(x, y, z))
  eee <- aaa + bbb + ccc + ddd
  paste(eee, "my_fxn", eee, sep = "_")
}
 my_fxn(df$x, df$y, df$z)
[1] "14500329.5724518_my_fxn_14500329.5724518" "64360436.579237_my_fxn_64360436.579237"   "240475836.750078_my_fxn_240475836.750078" "776392986.326892_my_fxn_776392986.326892"
[5] "2219080769.50416_my_fxn_2219080769.50416"

> my_fxn(x, y, z, data = df)
[1] "14500329.5724518_my_fxn_14500329.5724518" "64360436.579237_my_fxn_64360436.579237"   "240475836.750078_my_fxn_240475836.750078" "776392986.326892_my_fxn_776392986.326892"
[5] "2219080769.50416_my_fxn_2219080769.50416"
```

So on your update you are attempting to to assign

```
aaa = as.numeric(data$aaa)
bbb = as.numeric(data$bbb)
ccc = as.character(data$ccc)
```

Where `data$aaa` would be `data$x` and `data$bbb` would be `data$y`. The issue here is that there is no reason why the `x` column would be associated with `aaa` which is why in my previous answer I used `x, y, z`. in your case, the function will look for `df$aaa` which doesn't presently exist.

In order to generalize this the way you want so that you do not need to know the column names and hard code them into the function, You might try

```
my_fxn <- function (aaa, bbb, ccc, data) {
  if (!missing(data)) {
    aaa = as.numeric(data[,1])
    bbb = as.numeric(data[,2])
    ccc = as.character(data[,3])
  }
  print(aaa[1])
}
my_fxn(x, y, z, df)
```

Comment: I just updated my question to include a more accurate depiction of my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I updated the response. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I actually found the answer I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904328/writing-functions-with-a-data-argument. I didn't really have a great question formulated yet when I asked this question, but your response was helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Great, I had a look and I can see what you were getting at. Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix would be passing the column names as character to the function and modify the function so it gets the values from the dataframe columns.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(4:8), z = c(5:1))
my_fxn <- function(xx, yy, zz, data) {
  if(missing(data)){
    x = xx; y = yy; z = zz 
  } else {
  x <- data[[xx]]
  y <- data[[yy]]
  z <- data[[zz]]
  }

  aaa <- x ^ 2 + 5
  bbb <- (y * log(y) + 5) ^ 7
  ccc <- z + aaa
  ddd <- mean(c(x, y, z))
  eee <- aaa + bbb + ccc + ddd
  paste(eee, "my_fxn", eee, sep = "_")
}

my_fxn("x", "y", "z", data = df)
```

```
# [1] "14500329.5724518_my_fxn_14500329.5724518" "64360436.579237_my_fxn_64360436.579237"   
# [3] "240475836.750078_my_fxn_240475836.750078" "776392986.326892_my_fxn_776392986.326892"
# [5] "2219080769.50416_my_fxn_2219080769.50416"
```

Comment: p.s. This is not prone to errors. If you don't want to use `data` and pass characters as inputs, it will throw an error. Essentially, user-defined functions are designed for specific purposes so I don't see the necessity of making a function that would work with every possible input.