# Writing Functions With a "data" Argument

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to write a function that can take columns within a data frame or column names and the data frame they come from as arguments.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(6:10), z = LETTERS[1:5])

my_fxn <- function (aaa, bbb, ccc, data) {
  if (!missing(data)) {
    aaa = as.numeric(data$aaa)
  }
  print(aaa[1])
}
```

This function works fine when I provide columns from the data frame as the arguments:

```
> my_fxn(df$x, df$y, df$z, df)
[1] 1
```

It does not work if the column names and the data frame name are different from the names of the function's arguments:

```
> my_fxn(x, y, z, df)
[1] NA
```

It does, however, work when the column names and the data frame name are the same as the names of the function's arguments:

```
data <- df
names(data) <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
> my_fxn(aaa, bbb, ccc, data)
[1] 1
```

What is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort of piggy-back off of Cettt - something like this may be what you're looking for:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(6:10), z = LETTERS[1:5])

my_fxn <- function (aaa, bbb, ccc, data) {
  if (!missing(data)) {
    aaa = as.numeric(data[[aaa]])
    bbb = as.numeric(data[[bbb]])
    ccc = as.character(data[[ccc]])
  }
  print(aaa[1])
}

my_fxn("x", "y", "z", df)
#> [1] 1
```

---

With the use of `enquo()` from `library(dplyr)`, we no longer need to enter characters as the function variables:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_fxn <- function (aaa, bbb, ccc, data) {
  aaa <- enquo(aaa)
  bbb <- enquo(bbb)
  ccc <- enquo(ccc)

  if (!missing(data)) {
    aaa = as.numeric(pull(data, !!aaa))
    bbb = as.numeric(pull(data, !!bbb))
    ccc = as.character(pull(data, !!ccc))
  }
  print(aaa[1])
}

my_fxn(x, y, z, df)
#> [1] 1
```

More info about function building with `enquo()` and `!!` can be found here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#programming-recipes

---

Finally, a base R solution using `deparse()` and `substitute()`:

```r
my_fxn <- function (aaa, bbb, ccc, data) {
  aaa <- deparse(substitute(aaa))
  bbb <- deparse(substitute(bbb))
  ccc <- deparse(substitute(ccc))

  if (!missing(data)) {
    aaa = as.numeric(data[[aaa]])
    bbb = as.numeric(data[[bbb]])
    ccc = as.character(data[[ccc]])
  }
  print(aaa[1])
}

my_fxn(x, y, z, df)
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: This is a situation where I'd recommend using `as.numeric(data[[aaa]])`. It will fail if `aaa` has length greater than 1 and is guaranteed to return a vector.  `data[, aaa]` could return a vector or a data.frame, depending on the length of `aaa`.

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't want to provide arguments to the function that have to be character strings? I'd like to be able to write `my_fxn(x, y, z, df)` instead of `my_fxn("x", "y", "z", df)`.

Comment: Amazing. We can even put the `deparse` and `substitute` functions inside of that `if` statement to streamline things a bit. Thanks so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when calling `my_fxn(x, y, z, df)` the object `x` is not defined. 
Hence `df$x` does not return column `x` but `NA`.

Consider this small example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
x <- "y"
df$x # returns column x
[1] 1 2 3
df[,x] #returns column y since the value which is stored in x is "y"
[1] 4 5 6
```

To circumvent your problem you can use `data[, aaa]` instead of `data$aaa`.
Yet another alternative would be to use the `dplyr` package where you can use `select(data, aaa)`.